# Creating a new row that is the difference of one row from a scalar value

Tags: r

Assuming I have the following toy model, the dataset is called `Answer`:

```
Country    year     Y       Ex1       Ex2
A          2015    lala     5         5
A          2016    Popo     2         2
B          2015    baba     15        60
B          2016    nono     9         20
```

I want to find the mean of the value 2016 and 2015 across the board, for all numerical variables. Once I have the mean, I want new rows for both 2015 and 2016, highlighting the difference between the original value and the mean.

In this instance, `Country A: mean(Ex1) = 3.5, mean(Ex2) = 3.5`

My final dataset should look like:

```
Country    year     Y       Ex1       Ex2     demeanEx1    demeanEx2
A          2015    lala     5         5          .            .
A          2016    Popo     2         2          .            .
A          2015    lala     .         .          1.5         1.5
A          2016    Popo     .         .         -1.5        -1.5
B          2015    baba     15        60         .            .
B          2016    nono     9         20         .            .
B          2015    baba     .         .          3            20
B          2016    nono     .         .         -3           -20
```

If anyone is wondering, I am trying to implement fixed-effects manually, by creating demeaned values for my variables. I have 90 variables in my current dataset; finding means for all variables manually will be a long task.

I tried using the `demeanlist` command under `lfe` package, but R keeps aborting every time I try running it.

I know fixed effects can be run with `plm` package, using `model = within`, but I am trying to implement it manually.

Comment: Just wondering whether the difference from mean at the same row wouldn't be easier for you to process the data later `df1 %>% group_by(Country) %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Ex")), list(demean = ~ . - mean(.)))`

Comment: I did not realize that this would present my data in a better fashion. I will use this one. appreciate it

Comment: I wanted the answer in a dataframe format, so just to add to the answer, df2 <- as.data.frame(df1 %>% group_by(Country) %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Ex")), list(demean = ~ . - mean(.))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse`.  After grouping by 'Country', `transmute_at` to create the 'demean' columns by subtracting the values of 'Ex' columns from their `mean`, then bind the data with the original data (`bind_rows`), `arrange` by 'Country', 'year', `replace` the NAs in 'year', 'Y' for each 'Country' with the non-NA elements of that columns

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Country) %>% 
   transmute_at(vars(starts_with("Ex")), 
        list(demean = ~ . - mean(.))) %>%
   bind_rows(df1, .) %>%  
   arrange(Country, year ) %>%        
   group_by(Country) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(year, Y), list(~ replace(., is.na(.), .[!is.na(.)])))
# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   Country [2]
#  Country  year Y       Ex1   Ex2 Ex1_demean Ex2_demean
#  <chr>   <int> <chr> <int> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 A        2015 lala      5     5       NA         NA  
#2 A        2016 Popo      2     2       NA         NA  
#3 A        2015 lala     NA    NA        1.5        1.5
#4 A        2016 Popo     NA    NA       -1.5       -1.5
#5 B        2015 baba     15    60       NA         NA  
#6 B        2016 nono      9    20       NA         NA  
#7 B        2015 baba     NA    NA        3         20  
#8 B        2016 nono     NA    NA       -3        -20
```

---

Or in a slightly modified way

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Country)  %>% 
   nest %>% 
   mutate(data = map(data, ~ 
              .x %>% 
                   transmute_at(vars(starts_with("Ex")), 
                       list(demean = ~ . - mean(.))) %>% 
                   bind_cols(.x[1:2], .) %>%
                   bind_rows(.x, .))) %>% 
   unnest
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Country = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), year = c(2015L, 
 2016L, 2015L, 2016L), Y = c("lala", "Popo", "baba", "nono"), 
Ex1 = c(5L, 2L, 15L, 9L), Ex2 = c(5L, 2L, 60L, 20L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: with reference to transmute_at(vars(starts_with("Ex")): what if I have several different variables labeled differently. can I do something like, transmute those variables starting from column_4 to the end?

Comment: @JyothsnaHarithsa  If there are different variables, you can specify it as `vars(colname1, colname2,...` or if the columns still have some patterns, `vars(matches('Ex|Ix"))` depending on the match

Comment: @JyothsnaHarithsa  If you also know the column index, then it can be passed into it as well

Comment: How do you pass the column index into it?
I just used your code, and did the following:  transmute_at(.vars = vars(Age:Parkingzones),.....

(this is assuming there are n columns between Age and Parkingzones, and the mutation occurs for all the columns specified). This works, but knowing how to used column index will be useful. should I make a separate question?

Comment: @JyothsnaHarithsa  It would be just `transmute_at(1:3, ` if the columns are 1:3 and if there are indexes in a non-sequential order, `transmute_at(c(3, 5, 7:9), `

Answer (score 2):

A base R attempt, using `ave` to get the differences from the respective means, and some indexing to overwrite the sets of old and new values:

```
meas <- c("Ex1","Ex2")
s <- seq_len(nrow(dat))

out <- dat[rep(s,2),]
out[-s, meas] <- NA
out[-s, paste0("demean",meas)] <- lapply(
    dat[meas],
    function(x) x - ave(x,dat["Country"])
)
out

#    Country year    Y Ex1 Ex2 demeanEx1 demeanEx2
#1         A 2015 lala   5   5        NA        NA
#2         A 2016 Popo   2   2        NA        NA
#3         B 2015 baba  15  60        NA        NA
#4         B 2016 nono   9  20        NA        NA
#1.1       A 2015 lala  NA  NA       1.5       1.5
#2.1       A 2016 Popo  NA  NA      -1.5      -1.5
#3.1       B 2015 baba  NA  NA       3.0      20.0
#4.1       B 2016 nono  NA  NA      -3.0     -20.0
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat  <- read.table(text="Country    year     Y       Ex1       Ex2
A          2015    lala     5         5
A          2016    Popo     2         2
B          2015    baba     15        60
B          2016    nono     9         20", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Calculate and append the demean* columns and then rbind that to itself NA-ing out the appropriate columns.  Finally reorder.  No packages are used.

```
a <- transform(Answer, demean1 = Ex1 - ave(Ex1, Country), demean2 = Ex2 - ave(Ex2, Country))
a2 <- rbind(transform(a, demean1 = NA, demean2 = NA), transform(a, Ex1 = NA, Ex2 = NA))
a2[order(a2$Country), ]
```

The result is:

```
  Country year    Y Ex1 Ex2 demean1 demean2
1       A 2015 lala   5   5      NA      NA
2       A 2016 Popo   2   2      NA      NA
5       A 2015 lala  NA  NA     1.5     1.5
6       A 2016 Popo  NA  NA    -1.5    -1.5
3       B 2015 baba  15  60      NA      NA
4       B 2016 nono   9  20      NA      NA
7       B 2015 baba  NA  NA     3.0    20.0
8       B 2016 nono  NA  NA    -3.0   -20.0
```

or if we don't know how many Ex columns there are then first define `ix` as the column numbers of the `Ex` columns and calculate the demeaned values as `demeans`.

Create a data frame of three blocks of columns as shown.  Finally sort that.

```
# ix <- 4:ncol(Answer)
ix <- grep("Ex", names(Answer)) ##

demeans <-  Answer[ix] - sapply(Answer[ix], ave, Answer$Country)
names(demeans) <- paste0("demean", names(demeans))

aa <- cbind(
  Answer[-ix], 
  rbind(Answer[ix], NA * Answer[ix]), 
  rbind(NA * demeans, demeans)
)
aa[order(aa$Country), ]
```

Comment: I have around 80 columns, and they don't all start with "Ex", or any common phrase. is there a way to, say, apply this demeaned transformation to my columns starting from the fourth column?

Comment: Replace the line marked ## with `ix <- 4:ncol(Answer)` /